# Python printing array lists and length using definine function

Tags: python

I am trying to print the list in the variable "words" and print the length of each word.
I know how to print when you don't use def function but not sure how to print using below method.

```
words = ["good", "Joy", "computer"]
def list1(words):
    for x in words:
        print x
    return x, len(x)
print list1(words)
```

This is giving me:

```
good
Joy
Computer
('Computer', 8)
```

What can I do so it prints it like this.

```
good 4
joy 3 
computer 8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to make up your mind whether your function should print something or return a string that you would then print. here is an example of the latter:

```
words = ["good", "Joy", "computer"]

def list1(words):
    lines = ('{} {}'.format(x, len(x)) for x in words)
    return '\n'.join(lines)

print(list1(words))
```

if you like one-liners you could also do that:

```
print('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(x, len(x)) for x in words))
```

Comment: It would be conventional to build a list of lines then `return '\n'.join(lines)`.

Answer (score 0):

And an example of the printing without return value

```
words = ["good", "Joy", "computer"]

def list1(words):
    for x in words:
        print ("%s %u"%(x, len(x)))

list1(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to let the function return all the output as string, or print all output inside the function and return nothing.

1. Print the function's return value:

   ```
   words = ["good", "Joy", "computer"]

   def list1(words):
       return "\n".join((x, len(x)) for x in words)

   print list1(words)
   ```
2. Print inside the function only:

   ```
   words = ["good", "Joy", "computer"]

   def list1(words):
       print x, len(x) for x in words

   list1(words)
   ```